# How do I call a component from another function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create my own modal and I'd like to open it through calling a function, instead of putting the html directly. Is there a way to do that? Here's my code.

```
import { BiLink } from 'react-icons/bi';
import './ShareButton.css';

function ShareButton({postId}){

    function copyLinkOnClick() {
        const baseUrl = window.location.origin.toString();
        const urlToShare = baseUrl + '/post/' + postId;

        navigator.clipboard.writeText(urlToShare);
        //OPEN MODAL COMPONENT HERE.
    }

    return <div className="share-button-container">
        <BiLink className="share-button" onClick={copyLinkOnClick}/>
    </div>

}

export default ShareButton;
```

My modal component:

```
import './NuggetModal.css';

function NuggetModal({textBody}) {

    return <div className="nugget-container">
        {textBody} 
    </div>
}

export default NuggetModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useState` hook for this. Like create a state `showModal` and then set its value to `true` when you want to show the Modal otherwise set it to `false`. For instance

```js
function ShareButton({postId}){
    // modal state
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false). 
    
    function copyLinkOnClick() {
        const baseUrl = window.location.origin.toString();
        const urlToShare = baseUrl + '/post/' + postId;

        navigator.clipboard.writeText(urlToShare);
        // set showModal to true in order to show Modal
        setShowModal(true)
    }

    return <div className="share-button-container">
        <BiLink className="share-button" onClick={copyLinkOnClick}/>
        {/* Modal will only be visible when showModal state is true */}
        {showModal && <NuggetModal handleClose={()=> setShowModal(false)}/>}
    </div>

}
```

and in `NuggetModal` component just call `props.handleClose()` function when you want to close the modal as it will set the `ShareButton`'s `showModal` state to false